# Wifi to USB (wifi USB server)

Tags: usb, wireless-networking

I have a USB webcam, and I'm wondering if theres a box that will let me plug the webcam in and access it over wifi like this: http://www.belkin.com/networkusbhub/ except wireless.

Comment: I don't understand. That device you linked to takes USB devices and shares them over wifi. What else are you looking for?

Comment: No that deivce takes USB and shares them over a LAN(ie wired) connection. They show the outline of the wireless device which must be bought seperately.

Comment: Plug it into a computer and use Yawcam to broadcast the image over IP or use the device you linked to and connect it to a wireless router configured to be an adapter effectively making your webcam wireless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that most devices like the one you linked only tend to support media or printers, and not webcams.  Now, there are webcams that are network-capable, which may be a better solution here.

Answer (score 0):

some DLink router have SharePort which allows for USB over TCP